# Drupal 7 Book Module navigation

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

Normally book module automatically generated book navigation but i want display only 2 book from 4 how can i do it?

- book01

  - subbook01
  - subbook01
- book02

  - subbook02
  - subbook02
- <strike>book03</strike>

  - <strike>subbook03</strike>
  - <strike>subbook03</strike>
- <strike>book04</strike>

  - <strike>subbook04</strike>
  - <strike>subbook04</strike>

Thank you for all the replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new book, then add the two books you wish to display into this book. Such as:

- newbook

  - book01
  - book02

Then display newbook. I hope this helped.

Comment: thank occidio do you have idea if i want to hide only book02.

Comment: Without just changing the book that 'newbook' would contain, I am not sure. You can try adding this module to aid with the books. http://drupal.org/project/book_helper

Answer (score 0):

To properly be able to show/hide different books or sections you can install Book Helper (https://drupal.org/project/book_helper) which is great for allowing this type of customization that you are looking for.

Comment: btw I saw that this was answered in the comments but I just wanted to make it more explicit